# Migrating Lifery6.06 theme to Liferay 6.2

Tags: java, spring-mvc, liferay, liferay-theme, liferay-aui

I am new to Liferay, We have developed so many themes in Liferay-6.06, now we want to migrate those themes from Liferay-6.06 theme to Liferay-6.2.

What are the changes in Liferay-6.2 compared to Liferay-6.06?

What steps I need to care about while migrating?

How to convert the existing Liferay -6.0.6 theme to Liferay 6.2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget to migrate or convert existing themes.
Learn bootstrap and rewrite it all copying the look&feel.

Comment: liferay  6.2 classic theme is using bootstrap? How to use the boot strap in customized theme?

Comment: Yes, the classic theme is based on bootstrap. Starting a new theme based on _styled it's enough to have and to use bootstrap.